# Friend function and implementation

Tags: c++, friend

I came across the following code

```
class ExDer1 : public ExBase
{
public:
    friend int Der1Fn()
    {
        ....
    }
};
```

I am a little confused here with

```
        friend int Der1Fn()
        {
            //This has an implementation .Why is it a friend then ? since it can access the private/protected variables of the ExDer1  class ?
        }
```

Normally I would expect to see something like the following

```
friend int Der1Fn(); //No implementation. Indicating that the Der1Fn is a method outside this class
```

which basically would mean that a function `int Der1Fn()` would access the private variables of the class ExDer1. However this has an implementation. Could any one please explain what this means ?

**Update:**

So if I have the following code

```
class ExDer1 : public ExBase
{
public:
    friend int Der1Fn()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Der1Fn(); // error C3767: 'Der1Fn': candidate function(s) not accessible
    //.....
}
```

How do I call Der1Fn ?

Comment: Where did you learn that you cannot provide implementation of friend function inside class ?

Comment: I looked at example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2x4fzdz.aspx they did not have any example with an implementation that declared friend.

Comment: It means that's the implementation of the function. What don't you understand?

Comment: if the implementation of `int Der1Fn()` is inside the  `ExDer1` class whats the point of making it a friend . I think you misunderstood my question

Comment: just updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friend function ( or class) can be defined outside or inside class as well. If you define it inside you should provide matching declaration in correct scope, or argument dependent lookup will take place.

Following examples are logically same:

Example 1:

```
int Der1Fn();

class ExDer1 : public ExBase
{
public:
    friend int Der1Fn()
    {
        ....
    }
};
```

Example 2 (recommended):

```
int Der1Fn()
{
    ....
}

class ExDer1 : public ExBase
{
public:
    friend int Der1Fn();
};
```

> How do I call Der1Fn ?

As simle as [this](http://ideone.com/b58TZr).

Comment: just updated my post. If its equivalent to a function outside my class how do i access it ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar explanation added

Comment: Are you sure Der1Fn does not need parentheses in ExDer1?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the body of the friend function inside the the class definition (like for any type of function).

However the friend function follows the same basic rules of every function ever implemented : it's a bad practice to declare it in the class definition (inlining , recompilations of all dependent objects on change etc) .

You referenced a MSDN example. They just made the example like to show how scoping is done. The function Der1Fn() is in the global namespace, not in the ExDer1::Der1Fn() .

For your updated post :

The class Der1Fn() doesn't have access to the ExDer1's this (it's not a part of the class, it's an external function, think of it as being static).

However, inside the Der1Fn()'s body you can access private member variables of ExDer1 type of objects.

Comment: Sometimes implementing it in the class body is very convenient for template classes which tend to need header only code anyway..

Comment: True, but one needs to know both the benefits and the drawbacks. If you're not using templates or inlines it's unwise to implement big chuncks of code inside the header.

Comment: Just updated my post. If its an external function how do i access it ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar Just call it like any other external function.

Comment: You access it by calling Der1Fn() simple as that :). A quick side note, you will still need to declare int Der1Fn(); --notice the empty body-- outside the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

You'd make a function a friend if it needs to access private members of the class, but shouldn't be a member. The friend function can be implemented either inside or outside the class.

If a friend function is declared (and defined) *only* within the class, then it's scoped within the surrounding namespace, as if you'd defined it there; **but** it can only be found by *argument-dependent lookup* (ADL) - that is, it can only be found if called with a type from the same namespace as one of its arguments.

In this case, the function has no arguments, so can't be found at all - which is why you can't call it from `main`, or indeed from anywhere else. You'll need to declare the function outside the class, as well as in the friend declaration inside the class.

It would be more useful if it had an argument of the class type (or another type scoped in the same namespace); then it would be found when called with that argument type:

```
class ExDer1 : public ExBase
{
public:
    friend int Der1Fn(ExDer1 const &)
    {
        ....
    }
};

int main()
{
    ExDer1 obj;
    Der1Fn(obj);  // Found by ADL
}
```

Defining a friend inside a class is particularly useful for operator overloads which are (usually) only accessed by ADL anyway.